# R: How to add a dummy variable for counting the number of appearance

Tags: r, count

Here is my dataframe:

```
Number    Action
1         Running
2         Running
3         Swimming
4         Eating
5         Eating
```

I would like to add a variable to count the number of appearance, like this:

```
Number    Action    Count
1         Running   1
2         Running   2
3         Swimming  1
4         Eating    1
5         Eating    2
```

Comment: Next time please try and make your question reproducible by including the data using `dput(data)` and include what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                 Action = c("Running",  "Running", "Swimming", "Eating", "Eating"))

df %>% 
  group_by(Action) %>% 
  mutate(Count = row_number())

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   Action [3]
#>   Number Action   Count
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <int>
#> 1      1 Running      1
#> 2      2 Running      2
#> 3      3 Swimming     1
#> 4      4 Eating       1
#> 5      5 Eating       2
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>